# remove last character from Specific lines

Tags: batch-file, character

i would like to create a batch file that goes through txt files in a directory and every line that has #EXTINF in it, remove the last 15 characters..

basically if it is possible, i would like to trim the last 15-20 characters from any lines that is longer than a certain number.
for some reason i have a software that if the line is too long, it will screw up the data.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For one file:**

```
@Echo OFF

(For /F "Usebackq Tokens=*" %%# in ("MyFile.txt") Do (
    Echo "%%#" | FIND /I "#EXTINF" 1>NUL && (
        Set "Line=%%#"
        Call Set "Line=%%Line:~0,-1%%"
        Call Echo %%Line%%
    ) || (
        Echo %%#
    )
))>"MyNewFile.txt"

Pause&Exit
```

**For all files:**

```
@Echo OFF

For %%@ in (*.txt) DO (

    (For /F "Usebackq Tokens=*" %%# in ("%%@") Do (

        Echo "%%#" | FIND /I "#EXTINF" 1>NUL && (
            Set "Line=%%#"
            Call Set "Line=%%Line:~0,-1%%"
            Call Echo %%Line%%
        ) || (
            Echo %%#
        )

    ))>"%%@_New.txt"
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: Are you aware that tokens=* removes leading whitespace from a line?  "delims=" is always better for getting the entire line.

Comment: hey Elektro. your script worked but i need it to do two things: 1: support hebrew (probably UTF8) 2:it will keep the same name with the same extension.  what should i add to the batch? thanks a bunch

Comment: Use the codepage for hebrew, see about CHCP command and MS-DOS codepages. maybe you need to use **CHCP 862** or **CHCP 1255** instead of default **CHCP 850**. If my answer solved your really question then please use the accept button to accept the answer. I hope this helps. oh and also sear about **copy con** trick.

Comment: thanks buddy.just for tweaks, how can i tell it to trim say 15 last characters? change it to -15%%?

Comment: i added CHCP 1255 to the batch file but the output files are still with non recognize characters. can i set it so the output will apply chcp 1255 as well?

Comment: Like I said exist a difference from Recognize the characters (acces to file/folders) and let the CMD to correctly print those characters, if you want to print them then you MANUALLY need to do the character conversion: @Echo OFF
Set "string=hellç wçrld"
Set "String=%String:ç=‡%"
Echo %String%
Pause

Answer (score 0):

GnuSed is a better tool than batch for text editing.
This is for a single file

```
@echo off
sed "s/^\(.*#EXTINF.*\).$/\1/" "filein.txt" >"fileout.txt"
```

and for multiple files (will make fileone.new.txt from fileone.txt)

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b') do sed "s/^\(.*#EXTINF.*\).$/\1/" "%%a" >"%%~na.new%%~xa"
```